# Separate Python web scraped data by comma

Tags: python

I am new to web scraping with Python and found a quick tutorial online with some sample code. I adjusted some of the code to add another aspect to the result (output as a csv file). The code is scraping the info about different laptops (name, price, rating, specs).

The issue I am having is separating the specs with a comma in the output.

Here is the code I am using:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    products=[]
    prices=[]
    ratings=[]
    specs=[]
    driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2')

    content = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}):
        name = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'})
        price = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
        rating = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34'})
        spec = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3ULzGw'})
        products.append(name.text)
        prices.append(price.text)
        ratings.append(rating.text)
        specs.append(spec.text)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Product name':products, 'Price':prices, 'Rating':ratings, 'Tech Specs':specs})
    df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Here is the current output:

Tech Specs

Intel Core i5 Processor (5th Gen)8 GB DDR3 RAM64 bit Mac OS Operating System128 GB SSD33.78 cm (13.3 inch) Display1 Year Carry In Warranty

Pre-installed Genuine Windows 10 Operating System (Includes Built-in Security, Free Automated Updates, Latest Features)Intel Core i5 Processor (7th Gen)8 GB DDR4 RAM64 bit Windows 10 Operating System1 TB HDD39.62 cm (15.6 inch) Display1 Year Onsite Warranty

Here is how I would like the output to look:

Tech Specs

Intel Core i5 Processor (5th Gen), 8 GB DDR3 RAM, 64 bit Mac OS Operating System, 128 GB SSD, 33.78 cm (13.3 inch) Display, 1 Year Carry In Warranty

Pre-installed Genuine Windows 10 Operating System (Includes Built-in Security, Free Automated Updates, Latest Features), Intel Core i5 Processor (7th Gen), 8 GB DDR4 RAM, 64 bit Windows 10 Operating System, 1 TB HDD, 39.62 cm (15.6 inch) Display, 1 Year Onsite Warranty

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split tech specs if you need it. Right now you write tech specs as it is. Please take a look of updated code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

products=[]
prices=[]
ratings=[]
specs=[]
driver.get('https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo%2Cb5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2')

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True, attrs={'class':'_31qSD5'}):
    name = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3wU53n'})
    price = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_1vC4OE _2rQ-NK'})
    rating = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'hGSR34'})
    spec = a.find('div', attrs={'class':'_3ULzGw'})
    products.append(name.text)
    prices.append(price.text)
    ratings.append(rating.text)
    specs.append(", ".join([l.text for l in spec.find_all('li')]))

df = pd.DataFrame({'Product name':products, 'Price':prices, 'Rating':ratings, 'Tech Specs':specs})
df.to_csv('products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep=";")
```

I iterate through all specs and combine them using join and also I changed csv file column separator to ;

Comment: Your edit for adding the join worked great, thank you. I did keep the normal column separator since using ; put all column names into the same column and divided each spec into a separate column. Keeping the normal separator formats everything perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`selenium` is not proffered for such case, as the data is already visible within the `HTML` `script` tag, So you can use `requests` module with `bs4` to load the `JSON` data as below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    script = soup.find("script", id="is_script").text
    target = re.search(r"__INITIAL_STATE__ = ({.+});$", script).group(1)
    data = json.loads(target)
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4)) to see it in nice view
    print(data.keys()) # it's a dict, so you can deal with it.


main("https://www.flipkart.com/laptops/~buyback-guarantee-on-laptops-/pr?sid=6bo,b5g&uniqBStoreParam1=val1&wid=11.productCard.PMU_V2")
```